# ScrollView - How to let button always stay at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want the button to stay at the bottom of the screen, not of the Viewcontroller.

So my question is: How should I set constraints or write code to make my button always stay at the bottom of my screen?

I could like add a constraint to the top of the screen to make the button stay at the bottom, but that depends on the high of the device.

The button that should always stay at the bottom of the device

[image]

If I change the high of the Viewcontroller, the button moves to the bottom of the **Viewcontroller**, because of the constraint. And the right constraint would be one that goes to the bottom of the **screen**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add a constraint to the bottom of the `view` and set it to `0`?
This way it's always gonna snap to bottom.

Or if you're keen on using top constraint, you could calculate its constant programatically:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
    topConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - button.frame.height
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Where `topConstraint` and `button` are your `@IBOutlet`'s

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! I've just managed to got a solution on my own aswell. :')